# Class 'F0FDispatcher' not found in /var/www/joomla/components/com_ducatspremium/dispatcher.php on line 10

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I got  Class 'F0FDispatcher' not found in /var/www/joomla/components/com_ducatspremium/dispatcher.php on line 10 Error in Joomla Project.

My Dispatcher Code :

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die();
include_once JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/fof/include.php';
class DucatsPremiumDispatcher extends F0FDispatcher
{
    public function onBeforeDispatch() {
        $result = parent::onBeforeDispatch();
        if($result) {
            // Load Akeeba Strapper
            include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/media/akeeba_strapper/strapper.php';
            AkeebaStrapper::bootstrap();
            AkeebaStrapper::jQueryUI();
            AkeebaStrapper::addCSSfile('media://com_timesheet/css/frontend.css');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had same problem than I noticed that it's FOFDispatcher that is O not 0(zero).
So you should Try replacing `F0FDispatcher` with `FOFDispatcher` and let us know if you still have issue.